# Umami content not created

Tags: installation, installation-profiles

I'm creating a new Drupal 8 site using Lando/Pantheon - and then installing the Umami profile. I've done this before with no problems.

This morning when I try, the site is created and it looks like the Umami theme is in place. However, the content is not created.

Is there any way to create the content after the profile is installed?

Note: Oddly, drush is saying that the demo_umami_content module is not found but is able to find demo_umami_tour. ~/Desktop/lando/lando-panth $ lando drush pmi demo_umami_content demo_umami_content was not found.

Comment: Oddly, drush is saying that the demo_umami_content module is not found but is able to find demo_umami_tour.

~/Desktop/lando/lando-panth $ lando drush pmi demo_umami_content
demo_umami_content was not found.

Comment: How exactly did you install the Umami profile? via Drush or the Installer UI? Did you try this several times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Umami demo: Content* module is not found from Drush, nor is it visible in the list of modules, because it is set as hidden in [demo_umami_content.info.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.x/core/profiles/demo_umami/modules/demo_umami_content/demo_umami_content.info.yml). If you change the `hidden: true` line in `hidden: false`, you will be able to uninstall the module, and re-install it. This will execute again `demo_umami_content_install()`, which imports the content.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function demo_umami_content_install() {
  if (!\Drupal::service('config.installer')->isSyncing()) {
    \Drupal::classResolver(InstallHelper::class)->importContent();
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, the alternative is re-install Drupal using Unami as installation profile.

Comment: Thanks very much. The trick of uninstalling and reinstalling worked. Sorry I hadn't noticed the hidden option (not something I've run across before).

Comment: BTW, I had originally installed with the Umami profile - but somehow it had gotten itself in this odd state. Not sure how this was different than the times before I had done this type of setup. Oh well.

Comment: I know the feeling. I still find puzzling that installing the same module/profile can sometimes produce different results.